# PostgreSQL and pllua

Tags: postgresql, lua, luajit

I'm trying to build the pllua module but I'm having some trouble.

I think that the problem is on the wrong PostgreSQL version but I'm not sure, I'd be grateful if someone could help me.

Postgres location: **/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin**  (is the enterpricedb version without support)

Lua location: **/opt/myLua** (build with luaDist)

```
root@lua:/opt/BootstrapLuaDist/LuaDist/bin# ./luadist /opt/myLua/ list

Installed modules:
==================

  bit32-5.2.0   (Ubuntu-x86_64)  [provided by luajit-2.0.3]
  lua-5.1.5 (Ubuntu-x86_64)  [provided by luajit-2.0.3]
  luaffi-1.0    (Ubuntu-x86_64)  [provided by luajit-2.0.3]
  luafilesystem-1.6.2   (Ubuntu-x86_64)
  luajit-2.0.3  (Ubuntu-x86_64)
  luasocket-3.0-rc1 (Ubuntu-x86_64)
  srlua-5.1 (Ubuntu-x86_64)
  zlib-1.2.6    (Ubuntu-x86_64)
```

I've modified the pllua makefile:

```
# Makefile for PL/Lua
# $Id: Makefile,v 1.12 2009/09/20 14:20:48 carvalho Exp $

# Lua specific

# General
#LUAINC = -I/usr/local/include
#LUALIB = -L/usr/local/lib -llua

# LuaJIT
#LUAINC = -I/usr/local/include/luajit-2.0
#LUALIB = -L/usr/local/lib -lluajit-5.1

#myLuaJit 2.0.3
LUAINC= -I/opt/myLua/include
LUALIB = -L/op/myLua/lib -lliblua


# Debian/Ubuntu
#LUAINC = -I/usr/include/lua5.1
#LUALIB = -llua5.1

# Fink
#LUAINC = -I/sw/include -I/sw/include/postgresql
#LUALIB = -L/sw/lib -llua

# Lua for Windows
#LUAINC = -IC:/PROGRA~1/Lua/5.1/include
#LUALIB = -LC:/PROGRA~1/Lua/5.1/lib -llua5.1


# no need to edit below here
MODULE_big = pllua
EXTENSION = pllua
DATA = pllua--1.0.sql
#DATA_built = pllua.sql

REGRESS = plluatest
OBJS = pllua.o plluaapi.o plluaspi.o
PG_CPPFLAGS = $(LUAINC)
SHLIB_LINK = $(LUALIB)

#PG_CONFIG = /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_config
PG_CONFIG = /opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config
#PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

but the copilation rise an error and warnings:

```
root@lua:/opt/pllua-1.0# make
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fpic -I/opt/myLua/include -I. -I. -I/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/include/postgresql/server -I/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/include/postgresql/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/opt/local/20140108/fc7f8f12-7861-11e3-aaff-000c29d23b02/include/libxml2  -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include  -c -o pllua.o pllua.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fpic -I/opt/myLua/include -I. -I. -I/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/include/postgresql/server -I/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/include/postgresql/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/opt/local/20140108/fc7f8f12-7861-11e3-aaff-000c29d23b02/include/libxml2  -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include  -c -o plluaapi.o plluaapi.c
In file included from plluaapi.c:8:0:
rowstamp.h: In function ‘rowstamp_set’:
rowstamp.h:26:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘HeapTupleHeaderGetXmin’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  stamp->xmin = HeapTupleHeaderGetXmin(tup->t_data);
  ^
plluaapi.c: At top level:
plluaapi.c:41:3: error: unknown type name ‘int2’
   int2 len;
   ^
plluaapi.c: In function ‘luaP_gettypeinfo’:
plluaapi.c:149:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘GETSTRUCT’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     typeinfo = (Form_pg_type) GETSTRUCT(type);
     ^
plluaapi.c:149:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     typeinfo = (Form_pg_type) GETSTRUCT(type);
                ^
plluaapi.c: In function ‘luaP_modinit’:
plluaapi.c:350:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘heap_getattr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
           lua_pushstring(L, text2string(heap_getattr(SPI_tuptable->vals[i],
           ^
plluaapi.c: In function ‘luaP_newfunction’:
plluaapi.c:637:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   procst = (Form_pg_proc) GETSTRUCT(proc);
            ^
plluaapi.c: In function ‘luaP_pusharray’:
plluaapi.c:753:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fetch_att’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         luaP_pushdatum(L, fetch_att(*p, ti->byval, ti->len), typeelem);
         ^
plluaapi.c:755:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘att_addlength_pointer’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         *p = att_addlength_pointer(*p, ti->len, *p);
         ^
plluaapi.c:755:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         *p = att_addlength_pointer(*p, ti->len, *p);
            ^
plluaapi.c:756:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘att_align_nominal’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         *p = (char *) att_align_nominal(*p, ti->align);
         ^
plluaapi.c:756:14: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
         *p = (char *) att_align_nominal(*p, ti->align);
              ^
plluaapi.c: In function ‘luaP_toarray’:
plluaapi.c:954:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘store_att_byval’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             store_att_byval(*p, PointerGetDatum(v), ti->len);
             ^
plluaapi.c: In function ‘luaP_todatum’:
plluaapi.c:1047:15: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘heap_form_tuple’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
               dat = PointerGetDatum(SPI_returntuple(heap_form_tuple(ti->tupdesc,
               ^
plluaapi.c:1047:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘SPI_returntuple’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from pllua.h:18:0,
                 from plluaapi.c:7:
/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/include/postgresql/server/executor/spi.h:113:24: note: expected ‘HeapTuple’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern HeapTupleHeader SPI_returntuple(HeapTuple tuple, TupleDesc tupdesc);
                        ^
make: *** [plluaapi.o] Error 1
```

Thanks a lot

### -- update ----

I fixed (only in part) the problem. Dowloaded postgreSQL 9.2 from enterpricedb, now compilation is fine and pllua.so is installed in /opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/postgresql.

When I run : root@lua:/opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin# ./psql -U postgres -p 5435 -c "CREATE EXTENSION pllua" postgres

it raises an error:

ERROR: could not load library "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/postgresql/pllua.so": /opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/postgresql/pllua.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_math

Now what's the problem with luaopen_math ? May be I need to load some luaJit library before compilation ?

Answer (score 1):

This error:

> rowstamp.h:26:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘HeapTupleHeaderGetXmin’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

strongly suggests that you're compiling against a different PostgreSQL version than the PL/Lua sources you're trying to compile are from. Perhaps the extension isn't maintained and is for an old PostgreSQL version? Or perhaps you're trying to compile a version for PostgreSQL 9.4 against 9.3?

Update:

`HeapTupleHeaderGetXmin` was introduced in commit `37484ad2aacef5ec794f4dd3d5cf814475180a78` according to `git blame src/include/access/htup_details.h` and `git log -SHeapTupleHeaderGetXmin`. That commit first appears in the history in the `master` branch - it isn't present in `REL9_3_STABLE`. So yes, it looks like the PL/Lua you're trying to compile is the version for the latest un-released PostgreSQL.

You should be able to download a PL/Lua for 9.3 instead and compile that without issues.

Comment: I downloaded pllua from [link](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pllua) as suggested on http://pllua.projects.pgfoundry.org/#installation. The database is 9.3 from [link](http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads?ls=SEM&gclid=COGAyp7Ryb4CFZShtAodGG0Aow&quicktabs_postgres_plus_dwnlds=1#quicktabs-postgres_plus_dwnlds). I forgot to say that linux is an XUbubtu 14.04 . Whre I can qonload the 9.3 version of pllua ? I think that pllua is for PostgreSQL 9.2, but I'm not shure.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved !

First as suggested (thanks to Craig Ringer) i moved from postgrsql 9.3 to postgres 9.2

Second when you type make inside /opt/pllua-1.0 the compilation phase is ok but there are some problems with linker phase.

```
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fpic -shared -o pllua.so pllua.o plluaapi.o plluaspi.o -L/opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib -L/opt/local/20140108/fc7f8f12-7861-11e3-aaff-000c29d23b02/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-rpath,'/opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib',--enable-new-dtags  -L/opt/myLua/lib -llua
```

The linker doesn't recognize the shared library liblua.so located in /opt/myLua/lib, it's like the option -L/opt/myLua/lib -llua doesn't work (may be a Makefile problem)

So I moved liblua.so in /usr/local/lib executed ldconfig and now is ok:

```
root@lua:/opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/postgresql# ldd -v pllua.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3eddb000)
    liblua.so => /usr/local/lib/liblua.so (0x00007f2884eb1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2884aeb000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f28847e4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f28845e0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f28843ca000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2885337000)

    Version information:
    ./pllua.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /usr/local/lib/liblua.so:
        libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

How you can see now pllua is linked with the rigth liblua.so:
**liblua.so => /usr/local/lib/liblua.so (0x00007f2884eb1000)**

After that I loaded the module using PgAdminIII and tested the examples found at http://pllua.projects.pgfoundry.org/